# Automatic upload and update of the security certificate used by the API specifications for connecting to the backend endpoint

Tags: automation, ssl-certificate, wso2-api-manager

I am working on a api management project, i would like to know if there is a way to create and update security certifications automaticlly ?

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You could use the publisher rest APIs to upload certificates related to the backend endpoints. Check https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/publisher-apis/publisher-v2/publisher-v2/#tag/Client-Certificates .